# 100% height, centered faux column with sticky footer in right column

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

Given a 2 pane 100% height based faux column layout, I am trying to have a sticky footer in the right column that does not float over the column's content if the browser viewport is too small to display all the content.

My current problem is that the footer will float over the content if the browser viewport is to small.

This is what I am after:

[image: desired result]

With the code below though the footer (3) will move over the content (2).

Explanation:

1. Sidebar - this will have to extend to 100% height of the browser viewport or the combined height of 2+3 (whichever is greater)
2. Content - Varying amounts of content.
3. Footer - fixed height footer. This is either at the bottom of the browser window or below the content from no.2 whichever is greater.

Current html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="footer"></footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#content {
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height:200px;
}
```

Any help or pointers to get the footer to stay below the content no matter what would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/L6BLa/3/

Comment: That is the basic premise, however you will find that the green <div> moves on top of the grey <div> if you resize your browser. The green <div> should stop moving up when it touches the grey <div>.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L6BLa/3/ , but link on sticky footer of the comments below is useful too.

Comment: The latest fiddle you sent through has the working code so that is the accepted solution. Can you maybe update your first comment?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the concept you're looking for: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Applied the CSS/HTML on the site above to the Fiddle made by Nick: http://jsfiddle.net/L6BLa/2/

Note that you need to move `#footer` to the *outside* of `#wrapper`.

**Caveat:** `#sidebar` will only extend as far as the height of its own contents, *not* the combined height of `#content` + `#footer`. You can make `#sidebar` *appear* to extend the full length by giving `#wrapper` the sidebar background and making `#sidebar`'s background transparent.

Comment: Yep, the key was to have the background color of (1) give the appearance of a full length column. If anyone is interested, I can post the code for this.